# java script table row data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have JSON object like:

```
[{"ID":"4071","NAME":"ABC","NUMBER":102"},
{"ID":"4172","NAME":"XYZ","NUMBER":"103"},
{"ID":"4173","NAME":"LMN","NUMBER":"104"},
```

I have to create HTML table with single column where the HTML table row data is `NAME` from above JSON object.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LMN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have requirement like when I click on any row I need to get all the information like `ID`, `NAME` and `NUMBER` of row.

How can I achieve this? I mean for `td` tag what HTML control should I use so that I can store all the three fields in that control and only display `NAME` on that control?

Comment: is table comes from dynamically from same JSON object?

Comment: Yes table should come dynamically from JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can use data-attributes. Set data-id and data-number on td.
Read documentation about data-attributes: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

Comment: Try to open the link again

Comment: Any suggestion sorting table column by NAME with out using third party library ?

Comment: You can sort array using Array.prototype.sort method